# Can't create gitlab project with ansible

Tags: ansible, gitlab

I am trying to create a gitlab project via Ansible 2.4

So, I use [gitlab_project](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/gitlab_project_module.html) like this

```
- name: 'Gitlab create and local creat, commit and push with .gitignore file.'
      gitlab_project:
        server_url: https://gitlab.com
        validate_certs: True
        login_token: 9YmtcDSuFDo11A6DWxB7
        name: '{{longname}}' 
        state: present
        issues_enabled: True
        wiki_enabled: True
        snippets_enabled: False
      delegate_to: localhost
```

But I have a problem with ´delegate_to´ that seems to make it run on localhost, where I have not installed pyapi-gitlab.

So basically, here is my issue:

If I delete:

```
delegate_to: localhost
```

I get the error message:

```
fatal: [master1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Failed to connect to Gitlab server: 'message' "}
```

If I let

```
delegate_to: localhost
```

I get:

```
fatal: [master1 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Missing required gitlab module (check docs or install with: pip install pyapi-gitlab"}
```

But when I check it, it is already installed:

```
ansible-skel git:(master) ✗ pip install pyapi-gitlab
Requirement already satisfied: pyapi-gitlab in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (7.8.5)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pyapi-gitlab) (2.18.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->pyapi-gitlab) (2018.4.16)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->pyapi-gitlab) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->pyapi-gitlab) (2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->pyapi-gitlab) (1.22)
```

What should I do?

EDIT:

I also tried to remove `pyapi-gitlab` and `pip` from my computer and reinstall it with ansible but I get:

```
TASK [pip : Ensure Pip is installed.] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [master1]
fatal: [local_user]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Error: No available formula with the name \"python-pip\" \nError: No previously deleted formula found.\n==> Searching local taps...\nError: No similarly named formulae found.\n==> Searching taps on GitHub...\nError: No formulae found in taps."}
```

Comment: Ensure `pyapi-gitlab` is installed in the Python environment that Ansible runs (which might be, and likely is, different to the one you run from CLI).

Comment: updated... it became a little confusing, brew, pip, ansible ? Is it mandatory to run it on localhost ? Or should I just run it on host ( I already tried --> `fatal: [master1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Failed to connect to Gitlab server: 'message' "}` )

Comment: it appears to be the same problem than marked as duplicated, but the solution given in the other post is not working for me...